# Hvplot not updating through callback (otherwise working)

Tags: python, hvplot, holoviz, pydeck

Can somebody help me complete this demo. Everything is working. I have an interactive map that I populate from a Pandas Dataframe and when clicked it update the hvplot object, but for some reason the title update is visible only if I call on the object in another cell and the update is not displayed in the `pn.Row`. This is very hacky and I am open to other approaches. The ultimate goal is to have the hvplot react to the marker selected and display a hvplot from an `xarray.Dataset`.

```py
import hvplot.pandas
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import pydeck as pdk
from bokeh.sampledata.degrees import data as deg

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
hvplot.extension('plotly')
pn.extension("deckgl", stretch_width_policy="both")


DATA_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ajduberstein/geo_datasets/master/biergartens.json"
ICON_URL = (
    "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c4/Projet_bi%C3%A8re_logo_v2.png"
)
data = pd.read_json(DATA_URL)

INITIAL_HVPLOT = pn.panel(deg.hvplot.line(
    x="Year",
    y=[
        "Art and Performance",
        "Business",
        "Biology",
        "Education",
        "Computer Science",
    ],
    value_label="% of Degrees Earned by Women",
    legend="top",
    height=500,
    title="Initial Title",
))

INITIAL_VIEW_STATE = pdk.ViewState(
    latitude=51, longitude=7.4, zoom=9, max_zoom=16, pitch=0, bearing=0
)

icon_data = {
    "url": ICON_URL,
    "width": 242,
    "height": 242,
    "anchorY": 242,
}

data["icon_data"] = None
for i in data.index:
    data["icon_data"][i] = icon_data

view_state = pdk.data_utils.compute_view(data[["lon", "lat"]], 0.1)

icon_layer = pdk.Layer(
    type="IconLayer",
    data=data,
    get_icon="icon_data",
    get_size=4,
    size_scale=15,
    get_position=["lon", "lat"],
    pickable=True,
)

deck_gl_obj = pdk.Deck(
    layers=[icon_layer],
    initial_view_state=INITIAL_VIEW_STATE,
    tooltip={"text": "{tags}"},
)
deck_gl = pn.pane.DeckGL(deck_gl_obj, sizing_mode="stretch_width", height=600)


def panel_watcher(events):
    INITIAL_HVPLOT.object.opts(title=f"Map Clicked at {events.new.get('coordinate')}")

deck_gl.param.watch(panel_watcher, "click_state")
out_row = pn.Row(deck_gl, INITIAL_HVPLOT)
out_row.servable()
```